# rest_cannot_create_user

Tags: api, rest-api

I tried to register a new user with Wordpress REST API, but I keep getting the error message

> responseText: "{"code":"rest_cannot_create_user","message":"Sorry, you
>   are not allowed to create new users.","data":{"status":401}}"

This is the code I used

```
import $ from "jquery";

class TutorRegister {
  constructor() {
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    document
      .getElementById("tutorRegister")
      .addEventListener("submit", this.registerTutor);
  }

  // Methods
  registerTutor(e) {
    const fullName = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    const temp = fullName.split(" ");
    const warningAlert = document.getElementById("warningMsg");
    const signupBtn = document.getElementById("signup");

    const userData = {
      username: temp[0] + "_" + Math.ceil(Math.random(1, 999999) * 100),
      first_name: temp[0],
      last_name: temp[1],
      email: document.getElementById("email").value,
      password: document.getElementById("password").value,
      roles: "teacher",
    };
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", simple.nonce);
      },
      url: simple.root_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/users",
      type: "POST",
      data: userData,
      success: (response) => {
        console.log("Added user");
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log("failed to insert");
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

export default TutorRegister;
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you making this request on the WordPress site, or an external application?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm doing this on a WordPress site

Comment: Are you signed in as a user that can create users? How is simple.nonce populated?

Comment: No, I'm not signed in when creating a new user. It's done in the frontend.
I created the nonce using
`wp_localize_script('main-studymore-js', 'studymoreData', array(
    'root_url' => get_site_url(),
    'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'theme_url' => site_url('/wp-content/themes/studymore'),
    'current_user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
  ));`